# How to make read.table() ignore rows with error

Tags: r, csv, dataframe, row

I have to read a csv file with `read.table`, but I have a small problem: my csv contains some rows like that:

```
  A  B  C
1 2  3  4
2 2  5  6
3 4  8  error:8
. .  .  .
. .  .  .
. .  .  .
```

I would like to remove all the lines that contains error in my csv file or remove error and let the lines, I don't know if it's possible with R? 
this is my code:

```
file <- paste("C:\\test.csv")
table <- read.table(file,sep=",",header=T,fill=TRUE)
```

Comment: Hi, Take a bit of time and read the tag excerpt before tagging. [tag:dataframes] is for pandas, whereas you need [tag:data.frame] here. Be careful the next time. See this meta post. [Warn \[r\] users from adding \[dataframes\] tag instead of \[data.frame\] tag](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/318933)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
dat.file <- paste("C:\\test.csv")

# use readLines() to get file line-by-line 
dat.in <- readLines(dat.file)

# filter out "error"
dat.in <- dat.in[grep("error", dat.in, invert=TRUE)]

# turn structure into a string we can pass to textConnection
read.csv(textConnection(paste(dat.in, collapse="\n")), header=TRUE)
```

If you were on a Linux/OS X system, I'd have had you pipe the file through the system `grep`, but, sigh, #Windows.